# SASS if custom field condition

Tags: wordpress, sass

I trying add scss rule based on ACF field (or any field or post) value, but not sucess. How can I achieve code like This:

```
$option = $the_field('custom_field_name');

.p {
if($option == "1"){ $color = "red";}
}
```

Its possible in SASS?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $type: audi;   //value you selected
p {
   @if $type == benz {
      color: red;
   } @else if $type == mahindra {
      color: blue;
   } @else if $type == audi {
      color: green;
   } @else {
      color: black;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I know how to use "mixin" and "include", but how select color based on custom field choice? For example, when select from dropdown field "1" select color "#fff", when select value "2", select "#000".

Comment: @studioosiris Hi, i have changed my answer. Plz let me know if it works

Comment: Hi, not work, In Your example all "p" is red. I thing problem is how map ACF field - something like $the_field('custom_field_name')?

Comment: are you getting the value of option? Try with some hardcode value here with your code.